# How to import local .aar file to gradle.kts with exclusion?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to import a local .aar to my Android project, and want to exclude a few transitive dependencies from it.

In Groovy I can do

```
implementation(name: "abc", ext: "aar") {
    exclude(group: 'group', module: 'module')
}
```

However, I can't find an equivalent in Kotlin DSL. This is the thing I tried but didn't work

```
implementation(files("./libs/abc.aar")) {
    exclude(group: 'group', module: 'module')
}
```

What is the proper way to do so in .kts file?

Answer (score 1):

module -> build.gradle.kts :

```
implementation(linkedMapOf("name" to "abc","ext" to "aar"))
// or:
implementation(group = "", name = "abc", ext = "aar")
```

rootProject -> settings.gradle.kts:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs(rootDir.absolutePath +"/libs")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A local AAR file does not *have* transitive dependencies. Transitive dependencies come from metadata in an artifact repository, not from the artifact itself. Your first code snippet might be syntactically OK, but it is not having an impact.